# I am trying to put a div below two divs. The code is as follows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the div with id 4 to appear after the divs with ids 2 and 3 which have been placed side by side. But when I do this, the div with id 4 starts from the top itself (Not content wise, as the buttons in it stays below the content displayed in div 2 and 3. But my borders indicated that div 4 has started from the top itself, and the content are being displayed at the bottom of the div 4 which has started from the top itself.

```
<div id="1" style="width:100%;">
<div id="2" style="float:left; width:50%; border: 5px solid black" ></div>
<div id="3" style="float:right; width:50%; border: 5px solid red"></div>
</div>
<div id="4"style="border: 5px solid cyan"></div>
```

Comment: `<div id="4" style="clear:both;border: 5px solid cyan"></div>`

Comment: As a side note, the reason why boxes 2 and 3 are on different lines is because the borders are not included in the width. You can change that by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to both 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes @Mouser, that worked perfectly! Can you tell me the reason? I am new to this, so I don't know!

Answer (score 3):

That's because you didnt clear your floats. The easiest way to do is to add another `div` with class `clear`. And then in CSS define it

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/xt0ns1p7/

**EDIT**:
Also you should consider using `box-sizing: border box;` for your divs. If you use `box-sizing: border-box;` style, it will keep the width and height you set and all borders and margins will be pushed into the div.

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/xt0ns1p7/1/

Comment: `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` Use this all the time

Comment: Yes that was indeed the problem! What was the reason! And what are floats, sorry for asking such a question but I am new to this so I didnt know!